# Javascript replace has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var relName;
        $('.child').each(function() {
            relName = $(this).attr('rel');
            relName.replace('&','');
            $(this).attr('rel', relName);
            $(this).appendTo('#' + $(this).attr('rel'));
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

With this relevant HTML:

```
<div rel="MadDogs&EnglishmenHandpaintedfigurines" id="Figurines" class="category section child">
     <h3 class="categoryTitle">Figurines</h3>               
</div>
```

But for some reason, the replace has no effect whatsoever!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the whole of your problem, but the `&` needs to be `&amp;` in the HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`replace` returns string with replaced data. So you need to assign back to your variable.

```
relName = relName.replace('&','');
```

Comment: Awesome! I swear i'd seen it written differently before :S

Answer (score 3):

`replace()` doesn't change the original string, it returns a new one.

Comment: +1 because it's the correct answer, but it would have been even better with an example ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's not updating because you're not assigning the result to anything.

Try this instead:

```
$(this).attr('rel', relName.replace('&',''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat way to write it, using the [callback version](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex-%20attr) of <s>`attr`</s> basically every jQuery method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.child').attr('rel', function(i, relName) {
        $(this).appendTo('#' + relName);
        return relName.replace('&','');
    });
});
```

Comment: Very neat indeed. +1 for a novel solution. When you say nearly, what jQuery functions _don't_ have callbacks?

Comment: @JamWaffles: I didn't say "nearly".

Comment: You said `basically` instead. I just want to know what functions don't have callbacks, or if there's a list of them anywhere.