# how to strip (or regex match) a unicode character from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

A website I'm modding with a userscript has some text I want to modify.  The text appears to have a unicode character in it.  When I look at it on screen or even extract it to a variable with jQuery, it *looks* like this:

`2 others`

However, if I create my own variable with that same text and then do a comparison, they come up as false.  So I copied/pasted the site's text into vim and it looks like this:

`2<200e> others`

Best I can tell this is a unicode character for space (?).  I want to be able to match this string with a regex such as:

`^(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\s+(.*)`

but on this string with the embedded unicode character it fails.  (it works fine on my own typed text of '2 others').

Is there some way I can strip this unicode out of the text?  I tried the following, to no avail:

`text.replace('\u200e\','')`

`text.replace('200e','')`

`text.replace('\%20','')`

`text.replace('\%u200e','')`

Or, alternatively, can I adjust my regex to match either '2 others' or the same text with the embedded 200e unicode char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use an actual regex instead.

```
text = text.replace(/\u200e/g, '');
```

---

> can I adjust my regex to match either '2 others' or the same text with the embedded 200e unicode char?

You could just change the `\s` in your regex to include U+200E as well, e.g.

```
^(\d+(?:,\d+)*)[\s\u200e]+(.*)
```

Comment: hmm, doesn't work. example: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/HDzvP/ maybe I've got the wrong unicode?

Comment: @mix: The Unicode is right, but you did not assign the result back to the variable. **.replace is not a mutable method**. Please carefully read the answer, I've written "**text =** text.replace(...)". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718851/javascript-replace-has-no-effect.